# Why php module doesn't known as installed?

Tags: php

In my server, when I run this line:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
```

It throws:

```
[Tue Jul 10 21:57:21.446136 2018] [:error] [pid 32011] [client 167.99.34.190:27323] PHP Warning:  require_once(DOMDocument.php): failed to open stream: No such file or$
[Tue Jul 10 21:57:21.446181 2018] [:error] [pid 32011] [client 167.99.34.190:27323] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'DOMDocument.php' (includ$
```

Which means I have to install `php-xml` module.

I'm doing it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

And then:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But still the result of `echo "XML: ", extension_loaded('xml') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING';` is `MISSING`. Why? And how can I install it?

Comment: Are you sure Apache is running the same version of PHP that you installed the php-xml extension for? Also, what does you .ini file look like? You might need to enable the extension there.

Comment: For testing sake make a quick script calling phpinfo() and verify the extension is loaded. Also, make sure the extension is in your php.ini as well  ( and not commented out).

Comment: Are you actually calling `require_once(DOMDocument.php)` somewhere? Can you show the full code and the full error message?

Comment: @aynber: Looks like autoloader.

Comment: @aynber I don't have `require_once(DOMDocument.php)` anywhere. Autoloader thinks it is name a class and it has to include it. while it is a reserved thing in php.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Well no, I'm not sure about the version.

Comment: Restarting apache will only reload the config if you're using mod_php or mod_fcgi where apache manages the workers. If you're running PHP-FPM you'll need to restart FPM in order to reload the running configuration.

Comment: @Sammitch ah, eem do you know how can I restart FPM ? (I'm talking about the command)

Comment: `sudo service php-fpm restart`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by specifying the exact php version in the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: So you installed php from Ondrej Sury's repo? If yes, that's quite bit important, along with php version :)

Comment: @N.B. Well I don't remember I installed php from which repo, I guess I used `apt-get`.